# Maven for static web projects

Tags: javascript, maven, yui, minify

I want to use Maven capabilities for my static web projects containing images, javascript and/or css files.

I don't wanna consider anything about Java, jar packaging, ...

Basically, I need:

- "minify" resources: i.e.: some yui compressor plugin
- package my project (.tar.gz, ...)

Looking it up, I'd just found some  tags samples. But, nothing about the whole project.

For assembly `tar.gz`, I believe that Assembly plugin may be useful.
To minify and compress JS and CSS, I declare some compress/minify plugin.

How should I declare packaging tag in this case? The closer I thought was: `<packaging>war</packaging>`.

There's other way to declare it?

Does it make sense?

Comment: Here, there is an good example for assembly usage in this case: http://blog.eisele.net/2009/07/generating-static-war-content-archive.html

Comment: Recently, we changed our deployment architecture to Gradle. It improve some issues like flexibility, packaging, SCM tagging and delivery. It easy extensible, some Ant/Make/Maven foundations and modern. It is fully supported by Jenkins and can be run in any environment. We recommend it!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If your assembly descriptor does all the data processing (creating folders, copying files, etc.), then you can also declare the project to be a `pom` project.  This will result in maven skipping the default life-cycle phases like `compile`, `test`, etc.